# Execute a sql query and assign result to a variable in FTL file

Tags: sql

I want to execute a SQL query (if a value exist in a table or not) inside **ftl file** and based on the result 1 or 0 I want to do further operations.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from DataDb:tbl_conf
                                WHERE name="IsEnabled")
THEN
```

I do not want to execute this query again and again, store this Query's value to a variable and then use it anywhere in my ftl file.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Assign Count to Variable base on that you can check condition

```
declare @a int
SELECT @a =count(*) from DataDb:tbl_conf WHERE name="IsEnabled"
IF (@a>0)
THEN
```

Comment: Getting error: cursor.execute(query, args) ProgrammingError: SQLCODE -201 in PREPARE: 42000: Syntax error or access violation. i need to use it in FTL file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using following syntax in FTL file:

```
LET vIsFlag = (SELECT 1 from DataDb:tbl_conf WHERE name="IsEnabled");
IF vIsFlag > 0
THEN
```